# Using TaskDialogConfig with std::string

Tags: c++, mfc, taskdialog

I am trying to to create a Task Dialog, using the `TASKDIALOGCONFIG` strucutre. My application uses Unicode. This is my code:

```
string error_text = get_error_text();
string error_code = get_error_code();

TASKDIALOGCONFIG tdc = { sizeof(TASKDIALOGCONFIG) };
tdc.dwCommonButtons = TDCBF_OK_BUTTON;
tdc.pszMainIcon = TD_ERROR_ICON;
tdc.pszWindowTitle = _T("Error");
tdc.pszContent = error_text.c_str(); /* of course this will give a 
                                        const char* instead of a wchar_t* */
tdc.pszExpandedInformation = error_code.c_str(); // here is the same thing
tdc.hwndParent = m_wndParent;

TaskDialogIndirect(&tdc, NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

I have researched the problem a bit, but I haven't found a solution yet. Could anybody help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two options:

1. Use ANSI text. Do so by using `TASKDIALOGCONFIGA` and `TaskDialogIndirectA`.
2. Use Unicode text. Switch your strings from `std::string` to `std::wstring`.

I personally would recommend the latter option.

I would also recommend that you do not use `tchar.h`, and stop using `_T(...)`. Since you are only targeting Unicode, you should write `L"Error"` rather than `_T("Error")`. It only makes sense to use `tchar.h` if you are writing code that must compile for both MBCS and Unicode targets. That was a necessary evil in the days when we needed to compile for Win 95/98 and Win NT/2000. But those days are long gone.

Comment: Which one of those two methods recommend for my general programming? I mean, which one would be more efficient for my unicode application?

Comment: Hard to say from here. Personally, I tend to do Windows programming all UTF-16. So I use `std::wstring` and target `UNICODE` builds.

Comment: Ok then. I will replace the `string`s with `wstring`s. Thank you!